# how can I extend content in php page?

Tags: php

I want to make a remark column in a php page. If the content of remark is longer than 50 words  then the following words will become "...more". When the user check the "...more" so it can show the continue content without jump or refresh page.

I have no idea how to show the content after click the "...more"

```
$templen = $row['Remark'];
 if(strlen($templen)>30){
    echo "<td>" . substr($row['Remark'],0,30) . "<a href='' onclick=return" .substr($row['Remark'],30)."> ... more</a>" . "</td>";
 } else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['Remark'] . "</td>";
 }
```

Comment: You'll have to use javascript.

Comment: Do it with Javascript

Answer (score -2):

Use jquery slideToggle function like this:

```
if(strlen($templen)>30) {
    echo '<td>'. 
    substr($row['Remark'],0,30). 
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:$(\'#Remark\').slideToggle('fast');"> ... more</a>'.
    '<div id="Remark" style="display:none;">'.
    substr($row['Remark'],30).
    '<div>'.
    '</td>';
} else echo "<td>".$row['Remark']."</td>";
```